# How can I find the angle of a T shape in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4 to do some tracking, and I can get a contour of the shape I want, which is a T.

Input image:
[image]

I can use `cv2.minAreaRect(my_t_contour)` and get the angle of that rect, but that only gives me 0-180 degrees. But this is a T shape though, so I want to be able to tell 0-360. I was thinking of:

1. Split the contour into two rects
2. Get a line through the rects (either using skeletonize > HoughLinesP)
3. Determine which line is which, determine their gradient (using the coordinates I get from HoughLinesP) and then determine the direction of the T.

But I'm stuck at number 1, how can I split a contour into two shapes?

---

**Method 1**: draw center of contour and center of minAreaRect of contour

```
dst = cv2.cvtColor(r_target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (11, 11), 0)
ret,dst = cv2.threshold(dst,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cnts = cv2.findContours(dst, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    # get minAreaRect around contour and draw its center in red
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    cv2.circle(r_target, (int(rect[0][0]), int(rect[0][1])), 7, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # get moments of contour to get center and draw it in white
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cv2.circle(r_target, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

[image]

Next step would probably calculate a simple gradient between the centers to determine the angle.

---

**Method 2**: skeletonize the image and get lines using HoughLinesP.

```
dst = cv2.cvtColor(r_target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (11, 11), 0)
ret,dst = cv2.threshold(dst,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dst = 1 - dst / 255
dst = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(dst).astype(np.uint8)
rho = 1
theta = np.pi / 180
threshold = 1
minLineLength = 30
maxLineGap = 15
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dst, rho, theta, threshold, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)
for line in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(r_target, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]), (0, 255, 0), 1, 8)
```

But the lines don't come out nicely. This is how the skeleton looks like:

[image]

I'm still experimenting with the variables but is there a specific thought process around using HoughLinesP?

Comment: You're probably over-complicating this. I'll start checking the position of the center of  minAreaRect with the centroid/baricenter (check "cv::moments")

Comment: Finding rectangles would inturn use, hough transform based algorithms. Instead you can run morphological operations to just get skeleton of letter T in the image and then detect lines and angles between them.

Comment: @Miki so I drew the center of minAreaRect of the contour and the center of the contour itself (see edit), and the relationship between them does seem fairly consistent (other than the center of contour dancing around in some frames), so all I need to do is sort of get a gradient between the centers to tell the angle. I don't understand though, why is this working? Is it because the minAreaRect is just an approximation, but the relationship between it and the contour will always be the same?

Comment: @v.coder so I used scikit-image skeletonize of the letter but it turned out weird (see edit). I expected it to spit out two proper lines =) signifying a T. I'm running the skeletonize function on the thresholded image, am I not doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you can use PCA, find first component direction, and use it as an searced angle. You can check here for an example: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html